# BigQuery - An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 5423415

Tags: google-bigquery

We have some projects in which we had never had this issue and suddenly it started to happen, it happens in some scheduled queries that do update, delete, or merge, no matter if we try to launch the query as a normal query (not a scheduled one), the issue continues. In these cases, the query fails and we get this error:

"An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 5423415"

How can we face this issue? The same queries are running without troubles in other projects with the same structure of tables and schemas.

Comment: Are you still getting error messages or was this problem temporary?

Comment: @R.Esteves still happening. I created a ticket with additional info here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175233577